# How to print the value for each bin on the plot when plotting via seaborn histplot

Tags: python, seaborn

Lets say I am plotting a histogram with following code,
is there a way to print the value of each bin (basically the height of each bar) on the plot?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 4
sns.histplot(x=x, y=y, bins=4, binrange=[[0, 4], [0, 4]])
```

I am basically want to have a plot like this:

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be with Seaborn? I could do this with matplotlib's hist2d function but Seaborn doesn't return it's calculated histograms which you would need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain this is possible with seaborn (or at least not without calculating the histogram again separately with numpy/matplotlib). So if you're not tied to seaborn, here's an option for you to consider using matplotlib's [hist2d](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 4
hist, xedges, yedges, _ = plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=4, range=[[0, 4], [0, 4]])

for i in range(len(hist)):
    for j in range(len(hist[i])):
        plt.text(xedges[i] + (xedges[i + 1] - xedges[i]) / 2,
                 yedges[j] + (yedges[j + 1] - yedges[j]) / 2,
                 hist[i][j], ha="center", va="center", color="w")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what is h in your code?

Comment: It's a 2D array that contains the values of the histogram in each bin, it gets returned by `plt.hist2d`

Comment: I meant, you probably have a typo in `for i in range(len(h)):` and next line, you never defined `h`.

Comment: Ack sorry, that's meant to be `hist` - that's what I get for editing code after testing...